# I want to print a number i got from a def value. but i want to convert the def into an integer. Is there a way

Tags: python, arduino, integer, arduino-uno

```
import serial
import subprocess

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate = 9600, timeout = 1)
file = open('C://Users//adith//Documents//Code//Local-Sys-Files//Python//Sensor stuff uwu//comfirm.txt','r')
file1 = open('C://Users//adith//Documents//Code//Local-Sys-Files//Python//Sensor stuff uwu//comfirm.txt','r')
f=file.readline()
def getValues():
    ser.write(b'g')
    arduinoData = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
    return arduinoData

    
while (getValues<=40):
    file.write("False")
while (getValues==40):
    file.write("False")
while (getValues>=40):
    file.write("True")


while (f=="True"): (
subprocess.call("C://Users//Toasted//AppData//Roaming//Spotify//Spotify.exe")
)
```

I want to comare getValues with "40" but i can't do it since its not an integer so how could I change getValues into an integer.
getValues is basically reading of a serial monitor on Arduino

Comment: if it's not an integer than *what* is it? How would we know? Is it a string of `"40"`?

Comment: You don't actually call the function: `getValues` -> `getValues()`

Comment: Not that all the `while` loops make sense, especially the last one, which will be infinite almost certainly

Comment: Or `file.write()` given that `file` is opened in read mode. Or the next `file1 = ...` line...

Comment: 1) change all the `while getValues` to `if int(getValues())`. 2) are you sure you’ve received anything from Arduino? for debugging purpose, add a line before all the `while` with `print(arduinoData)` and report back what does it print?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the ardunioData to int and then use return and while calling the function make sure to use paranthesis'()'.

```
# In function
ar=int(ardunioData)
return ar

# when using while:
while getValues()>=40:
    file.write('False')
```